# In Rails, when should you use validations as opposed to database restrictions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In Rails, in order to validate information you can either use validations or database restrictions.

i.e:

Migration:

```
 t.string "name", :limit => 25
```

Validation from Model:

```
validates_length_of :name, :maximum => 25
```

I understand that validations prevent the form from submitting and migrations/database restrictions would prevent the data from saving into the database. But just curious, when you should use validations or database restrictions, or both at the same time?

Comment: This will have different opinions I guess, but I always do both whenever possible.

Comment: I think validations add more flexibility, easier to change and nicer to handle errors messages...and might be preferred if input is coming from users. Both is safest as you make sure it will not enter your DB.

Comment: @KcUS_unico Please note that uniqueness validations on the models do not actually guarantee uniqueness in the DB when you have multiple threads/processes running your app - please see my answer below.

Comment: Thx. I didnt know that but just read it in the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Validations are fast since they don't necessarily require a roundtrip to the database (for uniqueness they do) before you know whether or not the data is valid.  The downside to validations is that even when you have a uniqueness validation it can't 100% guarantee that uniqueness in the database.  This is because two threads could both check for uniqueness and then both add records to the database at the same time which end up failing the uniqueness check.  For that reason, any uniqueness validations should always be specified in the database and usually on the model too (Similar issue with record presence if one thread/process deletes it immediately after another thread has checked the presence but not inserted the new associated record yet).  Other format/length/etc validations can be specified on the model, where they're easy to update/change.

Answer (score 1):

Well if you use restrictions at the database level its harder to know when what its happening. If you add it to the validation its clear on the model. its easier to change and its clear for all the developer what is what.

I like validation when ever I can use it and avoid database restriction if i can

I hope that this helps :)